# Possible to partition five elements by median with six comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection, median

Given five random elements, it's possible to find the median using just six comparisons. But I have an extra requirement in that the following condition is also satisfied:

a < c && b < c && c < d && c < e

It is NOT required for a < b or d < e.

I've been able to satisfy this condition using **seven** comparisons, but not six. This is my code, which should be self explanatory:

```
void medianSort(int[] arr)
{
    assert(arr.length == 5);

    void sortPair(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        if(a > b) swap(a, b);
    }

    sortPair(arr[0], arr[1]);
    sortPair(arr[3], arr[4]);
    sortPair(arr[0], arr[3]);
    sortPair(arr[1], arr[4]);
    sortPair(arr[2], arr[3]);
    sortPair(arr[1], arr[2]);
    sortPair(arr[2], arr[3]);
}
```

I have a quick sort that I wish to enhance by using a median of five to choose the pivot. By satisfying that condition, five elements are already sorted.

Is it possible to accomplish this in six comparisons, or is seven the best I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grinded away at the problem for two hours, but I found a solution. The important thing is to keep track of the comparisons made, which I've done in great detail with the comments. The function is written in D.

```
void medianSort(alias pred = "a < b", T)(ref T a, ref T b, ref T c, ref T d, ref T e)
{
    alias binaryFun!pred less;
    bool greater(T a, T b){ return !less(a, b); }

    if(greater(a, b)) swap(a, b); // #1
    // a<b
    if(greater(d, e)) swap(d, e); // #2
    // a<b d<e

    if(less(a, d)) // #3
    {
        // a<d<e a<b
        // eliminate a
        // d<e
        if(greater(b,c)) swap(b,c); // #4
        // b<c d<e
    }
    else // if(less(d, a))
    {
        // a<b d<a d<e
        // d<a<b   d<e
        swap(a, d);
        // a<d<b   a<e
        // eliminate a
        // d<b
        swap(d, b);
        // b<d
        if(greater(c, e)) swap(c, e); // #4
        // b<d c<e
        swap(c, d);
        // b<c d<e
    }

    // b<c d<e
    if(less(b, d)) // #5
    {
        // b<c b<d d<e
        // b<c b<d<e
        // eliminate b
        // d<e
    }
    else
    {
        // b<c d<e d<b
        // d<b<c d<e
        swap(b, d);
        // b<d<c b<e
        // eliminate b
        // d<c
        swap(c, e);
        // d<e
    }

    // d<e
    // median is smaller of c and d
    if(greater(c, d)) swap(c, d); // #6
}
```

Python: http://pastebin.com/0kxjxFQX

Comment: Let a=1,b=5,c=4,d=2,e=3. Your algorithm gives 1,4,5,2,3. Moreover, I have an easy formal proof that less than 5 comparisons is impossible. Somewhat more involved proof pushes it up to 6. I'll try to post it when I have more time.

Comment: It works, I tested it over thousands of permutations. I've also implemented it in my quick sort and it's working just fine there. I suspect you did something wrong as I got the result 1,2,3,5,4. It also does 6 comparisons, see the last statement, // #6.

Comment: Sorry, I did not scroll down. Good job!

Comment: By the way, you do not need to check it on "thousands of permutations". There are only 5! = 120 and you can generate them all with [Narayana's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) (good one to know for interviewing :) ). I've checked your Python program with it and it works. Good job, again!!

Comment: In the python code: try `tmp = medianSort(0, 1, 10, 3, 4)`. I get `[0,1,3,10,4]`. I don't think this works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is a proof that you need at least 6 comparisons.

First of all, note that all the information we obtain is based only on comparisons. We can do swapping in the very end based on what transpired during the comparisons steps. Also note that our comparisons can be based only on comparisons done *previously*. For example, the first step in the algorithm will be always the same as no comparisons have been done previously; the second comparison already can depend on the first, etc.

Let's "name" the elements according to their magnitude - 1,2,3,4,5. They can appear in the input in any order. Now, we need *at least four comparisons* to order the elements correctly. They are:

```
3 > 2           [1]
3 > 1 OR 2 > 1  [2]
3 < 4           [3]
3 < 5 OR 4 < 5  [4]
```

Any other comparison is *extra*. Also, if we can't avoid both comparisons in `[2]` or both comparisons in `[4]` - those also become *extra*.

As the initial permutation can be anything, we immediately get one *extra* comparison: `1 < 5` (this is important to understand: as our algorithm always takes the same first two elements according to how they are presented in the input, say *a* and *b*, there is always a possibility that `a = 1` and `b = 5`).

Now, there are two cases to consider for the second step:

**Case 1:** we compare two elements other than `1` and `5`. As we can't distinguish among `2`,`3`, and `4` at this stage we immediately get the second *extra* comparison: `2 < 4`. So we are up to 6 comparisons.

**Case 2:** we compare `1` or `5` with one of `2`,`3`, or `4`. Without loss of generality let's assume that we are comparing `1`. As we can't distinguish among `2`,`3`, ant `4` we get our second *extra* comparison: `1 < 4`. QED